# Shortcut to show / hide the layers as per the sequence?

Tags: qgis, layers, editing

Does anyone know any shortcut to display / hide the layers as per the order? For example, F1 displays and hides layer 1, F2 displays and hides layer 2.
I found the shortcut to hide all the layers and hide the selected layer, but for what I want it does not work, because I need to edit layer 1 (shp) and toggle between displaying and hiding layer 2 (raster).
QGIS 2.18

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for but close.  The following code when run from the QGIS 2.x Python console (tested on 2.16.0) will let you to choose a layer then toggle its visibility.

- Selecting a layer then pressing `Alt Z` will choose it for toggling.
- Pressing `Z` will toggle the chosen layer's visibility regardless of which layer is currently active.

Here's the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QShortcut, QKeySequence
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
currentToggleNode = root.findLayer(iface.activeLayer().id())

def setToggleLayer():
  currentToggleNode = root.findLayer(iface.activeLayer().id())

def toggleLayer():
  new_state = Qt.Checked if currentToggleNode.isVisible() == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked
  currentToggleNode.setVisible(new_state)

shortcutSetToggleLayer = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.AltModifier + Qt.Key_Z), iface.mainWindow())
shortcutSetToggleLayer.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcutSetToggleLayer.activated.connect(setToggleLayer)

shortcutToggleLayer = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Z), iface.mainWindow())
shortcutToggleLayer.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcutToggleLayer.activated.connect(toggleLayer)
```

You'll need to run the above code from the Python console once each time you start QGIS (you can save it in a script file to avoid retyping; see the QGIS docs for details).  If you get any error messages you'll need to restart QGIS before fixing the problematic code since Python state is pretty persistent within a QGIS session.

Known bugs:

- Will probably break if toggling (`Z`) is used before a toggle layer has been selected (with `Alt Z`)